# Double 'each' loop to find the smallest value in an Array

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to implement the Pinterest wall, as described here : [how to replicate pinterest.com's absolute div stacking layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109362/how-to-replicate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout/7128902#7128902)

Anyway, I'm stuck at one point where I need to find the *index* of the **smallest value** in an Array, but at the same time, **add the height** of my *current* block to that value (so that the smallest value isn't always the same).

```
var grid = new Array(4); // 4 as example

// Add values to the Array
$.each(grid, function(j) {
    grid[j] = j;
});
var smallest_index = 0;
var smallest_value = grid[0];

// Find the index of the smallest value in the Array
SmallestValueIndex = function() {
    $.each(grid, function(i, v) {
        if (v < smallest_value) {
            smallest_index = i;
            smallest_value = v;
        }
    });
}

// Go through all my '<div>' and add the height to the current smallest value
$.each(blocs, function() {
    SmallestValueIndex();
    var h = $(this).height();
    grid[smallest_index] += h;
});
```

Each time, the smallest value should be different because I add the height to the *previous* smallest value (so it's not the smallest value anymore).

But in my tests, it remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It uses the native `Math.min` function, rather than a inefficient jQuery loop:

```
$.each(blocs, function() {
    var lowest = Math.min.apply(null, grid);
    var index = grid.indexOf(lowest);
    grid[index] += $(this).height();
}
```

First, `Math.min()` gets the lowest number out of all grid elements. Then, `grid.indexOf()` is used to find the position of this element. Finally, the height is added to the element in grid at index `index`.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly the function I was looking for. I was afraid, though, of not being able to access the _index_ of that value, but you showed me how.

One question: what does the 'null' do in the apply() function?

Comment: `.apply` accepts two arguments: The `this` keyword of the called function will be set to the first argument, and the list of arguments is specified through the second argument. In this case, the `this` keyword is irrelevant, and can be set to anything. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Keep in mind that older versions of IE don't have Array.indexOf() so you will have to shim that method if you want to use it in all browsers.