# How to display divs in columns- fluid design

Tags: css

```
 <div id="foo">
    <div class="bar">
       there are very many divs like this  
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#foo{
    margin: 10px auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    min-width: 800px;
}
.bar{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 450px;
    min-height: 280px;
}
```

The div #foo can have a variable width from 800px to 100% of containing media and that the div .bar can have a variable height. On wide displays I want three columns of .bar divs but since they are variable height it's like they slide to the left of the div above hence those on the left have spaces above them. How do I make them float upwards. I hope I made sense.

Comment: Are you looking to do something like what Pinterest does?  Something like this: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: Yes, and facebook too used to do that on wide panel displays. All i want to do is to remove space above the the divs when they float to the left

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at this post: [Does anyone know how Pinterest.com's layout works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000119/does-anyone-know-how-pinterest-coms-layout-works) and possibly these jQuery plugins: http://masonry.desandro.com/ and http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin.

A CSS3 solution: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Comment: See also [this](http://benholland.me/javascript/how-to-build-a-site-that-works-like-pinterest/) and ESPECIALLY [this](http://www.script-tutorials.com/?s=pinterest+step)