# How is this website made? Div align and stick to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

EXAMPLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/BpYZn/

Here is was I want to get:
http://www.akinyapin.com/

Depending on the browser size the divs realign from 3 per row to 5 per row(maybe more, my screen is 1366 × 768, can't check).

I tryed just making the div elements to align with the float attribute.
It works partially, they shrink to 3 per row depending on browser size but they wont "stick" to each other. There are big gaps between the divs in different rows.

The second website uses the "position:absolute". Is there a script for that kind of thing that anyone knows maybe?

This is the div's css

```
.box1{
padding:7px;
position:relative;
margin:1px;
background-color:white;
width:230px;
min-height:200px;
float:left;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: You need [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replicate pinterest.com's absolute div stacking layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109362/how-to-replicate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout)

Comment: not a duplicate because I have no idea what pinterest is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website uses a javascript plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which is doing the stacking divs magic. I don't see this effect being accomplished with pure css.