# Arrange inline-block divs nicely

Tags: css, html, positioning, floating

I have a set of divs with this layout:

```
div.post_summary {
    clear: none;
    width: 170px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #FF5900;
}
```

It now looks like:

[image]

But I want it to look like:

[image]

The order of the divs in no way matters. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replicate pinterest.com's absolute div stacking layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109362/how-to-replicate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout)

Comment: @TImCooper is there a no-javascript solution as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since order doesn't matter, you can do this with CSS columns:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/CcGlE

```
div.container { /* container holding all of your `div.post_summary` elements */
  columns: 20em; /* desired width of the columns */
}

div.post_summary {
    margin: .5em;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

div.post_summary:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Make sure you check http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn to see which prefixes you need.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not compatible with IE. Is there a CSS-only solution which works in all browsers?

Comment: Your question didn't specify browser support.  CSS Columns or Flexbox (columns orientation) are your only options for pure CSS, and only available in IE10+.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer which indeed answers the question. I'm not going to use it though, but thanks anyway!