# How to display photos with captions in grid view like http://pinterest.com/ using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need to show photos with caption in grid view like http://pinterest.com/. 
What i want to do:
As in http://pinterest.com/, some images are showing as different width  & height. So i want to implement same thing,
In my case, images are coming from database (mysql, php) so all images are of same size. I need some js or jquery code to show them in grid view but random images having different size.

Comment: If all the image are the same size, just use CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replicate pinterest.com's absolute div stacking layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109362/how-to-replicate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is pInterest's has 5 columns, all of which are of equal width. The images are all of different dimensions so this requires them to resize all the images down to this equal width and allows them to have these different height images.

If, as you say, all of your images are of equal height and width then you won't get this effect without having different column widths. But then all of your images will be the same width and height as all of the others in that column.

There are several gridView plugins you can use like-

- [Masonary](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
- [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

This is an example of the different widths I've explained above.

**pInterests current view**
[image]

**what yours would look like with all of equal widths.**
[image]

**What yours would look like with different widths**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First use this for the Pinterest-like grid: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Then if you are getting an array from your database with your images URL try this code:

```
//'Shuffle' the array for random order
<?php shuffle( $arrayImg ); ?>
// Iterates over the array
<?php foreach ( $arrayImg as $src ): ?>
  // Random images width between 200 and 300 with 'rand'
  // Maybe the random width is contradictory... but test it yourself =)
  <img src="images/<?php echo $src ?>" width="<?php rand(200,300) ?>">
<?php endforeach ?>
```