# convert divs displaying as row to divs displaying as column

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have as the following divs. Suppose each div is floated left or set display to inline-block.

```
+-----------+ +-----------+ +--------------+
|    1      | |     2     | |              |
+-----------+ |           | |      3       |
              +-----------+ |              |
                            +--------------+
+-----------+ +-----------+ +--------------+
|     4     | |     5     | |              |
+-----------+ |           | |      6       |
              +-----------+ |              |
                            +--------------+
+-----------+ +-----------+ +--------------+
|           | |    8      | |      9       |
|    7      | +-----------+ |              |
|           |               +--------------+
|           |
+-----------+
```

I want to achieve like this

```
+-------------+ +-----------+ +-------------+
|     1       | |     4     | |             |
+-------------+ +-----------+ |      7      |
+-------------+ +-----------+ |             |
|      2      | |      5    | |             |
|             | |           | +-------------+
+-------------+ +-----------+ +-------------+
+-------------+ +-----------+ |      8      | 
|             | |           | +-------------+
|       3     | |       6   + +-------------+
|             | |           | |     9       |
|             | +-----------+ |             |
+-------------+               +-------------+
```

I know I can do this by column-wise as this

```
<div class="col1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div> 
<div class="col2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="col3">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

But In my website there more pages like this, so I would like to achieve without touching markup. Is there any idea to perform this with css or any javascript/jquery method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replicate pinterest.com's absolute div stacking layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109362/how-to-replicate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using JS and jQuery** it's quite easy to turn **"Mission Impossible"** into **"Alice in Wonderland":**

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ihilac/3/)**</kbd>

HTML sample:

```
<div id="cont"> 

   <div></div>
   <!-- ...more  <div></div> here ... -->

</div>
```

CSS sample (the `.col` will be added by jQuery):

```
#cont .col > div{
  position:relative;
  width:250px;
  background:#eee;
  margin:2px;
  padding:15px;
}

.col{
  float:left;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    var cells = $('#cont > div');

    for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i+=3) {
      cells.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='col' />");
    }

});
```

Comment: @C-Link you're welcome! :) Glad you did it! I was afraid you're stuck with the basics of jQuery... But great!

Comment: Just one thing remaining to do: There is 14 divs in my site, so I did i+5 and if it was 20 I would have done i+7 but exactly how could I do for the best that I need not to edit each time the div increases.

Answer (score -1):

Not touching mark-up is what makes things sticky.  David DeSandro made a well working tight cascading grid system with jQuery called Masonry, it may be able to help you out with this:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: It is great that you are trying to help the asker out. However, leaving an answer with only a link can be harmful in some cases. While your answer is good now, if the link were ever to die, your answer would lose it's value. So it will be helpful if you summarize the content from the article in your answer. See [this](http://goo.gl/wQTjc) question for clarification.