# How to place the blocks in such a way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to place the blocks in such a way?

Link of the image -> http://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image664571.jpg

```
<ul class="list">
      <li class="item">
        <a href="/" class="link">текст
          <img src="" class="img">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="/" class="link">текст
          <img src="" class="img">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="item">
        <a href="/" class="link">текст
          <img src="" class="img"> 
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: either you can use masonary jquery plugin or in CSS3 you can use `Multiple Columns`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to replicate pinterest.com's absolute div stacking layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109362/how-to-replicate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout)

Comment: You might also like to look at Bootstrap CSS http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

Answer (score 0):

I would make 4 separate CSS columns and fill each of them separately.