# Neatly arrange different sized images into a grid

Tags: css, image, grid

I'm trying to arrange images into a neatly packed grid like in the screenshot. The images come from a CMS so they can be any size.

How can I make this work either using CSS or JS?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various layout `js` libraries already present like

1. [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/)
2. [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
3. [Gridster](http://gridster.net/)
4. [Flex](http://www.jsonenglish.com/projects/flex/)
5. [Waterfall](http://wlog.cn/waterfall/)
6. [Blockslt](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/)

You can check [how to replicate pinterest.com's absolute div stacking layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109362/how-to-replicate-pinterest-coms-absolute-div-stacking-layout)

Comment: I don't believe any of these provide the effect I want. My images can be any size but the images in these examples are always fixed width. 1/4 1/3 1/2

Comment: Check appended method in http://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html images being inserted are of variable sizes,
Direct codepen link http://codepen.io/desandro/full/HFbia

Comment: They're still using the same group of widths e.g. 20% 50% 100% etc. Thinking about this more is seems quite complicated or maybe even impossible. I'll just have to settle for using Packery. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this, hopefully this will help. Just you have to add the margin in between the images of your choice.

```
<div id="image-container">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/300/">
    <img src="http://fakeimg.pl/250x100/">
    ...
</div>

#image-container {
  line-height: 0;

  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -moz-column-gap:      0px;
  column-count:         5;
  column-gap:           0px; 
}
```

Comment: Great answer, once the container is full, is there a way to make the overflow scrolling vertical rather horizontal? (Assuming your container has a set width/height of say 300px X 300px)