# Masonry like layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve and Masonry like layout with flexbox only.

i figured i would need to use a mix of columns and rows, but what i cant achieve is that the elements will all have the same distance (like stacked) below and above each other, as well as the second element in the first row wont align towards the first...is it even possible to achieve it without js? Thanks a lot

**

> UPDATE:

**

I managed to pull the middle and right column up in the second row,
so its just the second element that needs to be aligned with the middle column....so i guess js is not really neded

http://codepen.io/HendrikEng/pen/PpzYqM?editors=1100

This is how it should look:

[image]

HTML

```
<section>
  <div class="c-team-tiles">
    <div class="c-team-row">
      <figure class="c-team-tile">
        <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/390x590" alt="">
        </div>
        <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
          <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
          <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="c-team-tile">
        <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/590x390" alt="">
        </div>
        <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
          <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
          <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="c-team-row">
      <div class="c-team-column">
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x330" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x590" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x590" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x590" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>

      </div>
      <div class="c-team-column">
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x590" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x330" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x420" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x330" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x330" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="c-team-column">
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x450" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x330" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x590" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x330" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="c-team-tile">
          <div class="u-margin-bottom c-team-tile__img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/390x450" alt="">
          </div>
          <figcaption class="c-image-tile__cpt">
            <h4 class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Name</h4>
            <p class="u-margin-bottom-tiny">Position</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.c-team-row {
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.c-team-coumn {
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.c-team-tile {
  align-self: auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  order: 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B Let's give the author of the [`Pinterest layout script`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7128902/1891677) script the credits on this one.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, you should post that link in the other question, where it would be more relevant.

Comment: thanks guys, i came super close with flexbox only, the only thing was the second element, thats why i thought i wont need a masonry js, and i could maybe just pull the two columns  below up with negative margin.